# Joint convergence in distribution

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-calculus

I've one question concerning convergence in distribution of random variables: Let $X_n \rightarrow X$ and $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ for $n \to \infty$ where $\rightarrow$ denotes convergence in distribution. Furthermore assume $X_n$ and $Y_n$ to be independent for all $n$ and also $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Does $(X_n,Y_n) \rightarrow (X,Y)$ hold (meaning that the joint distribution also converges)?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because if we look at the joint characteristic function:

$$Ee^{i(uX_n + vY_n)} = Ee^{iuX_n}Ee^{ivY_n} \to Ee^{iuX}Ee^{ivY} = Ee^{i(uX + vY)}$$

Comment: OK, this is convincing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @pierreparis1 you are welcome!