# Convergence in distribution for continuous functions of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, independence

If two sequences of random variables $\{X_n\},\{Y_n\}$ are such that $X_n \xrightarrow{d}X,\ Y_n \xrightarrow{d}Y $, i.e, they converge in distribution to $X$ and $Y$ respectively, where $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent.

I want to prove that for any continuous function $g(x,y)$, $g(X_n,Y_n) \xrightarrow{d} g(X,Y)$ holds.

Can anyone help me with this ? I am using the following definition of convergence in distribution:
$$
X_n \xrightarrow{d} X \Leftrightarrow \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[f(X)]
$$
for all $f$ bounded continuous.

I could prove that $g(X_n) \xrightarrow{d} g(X)$ and $g(Y_n) \xrightarrow{d} g(Y)$ but how do I prove joint convergence ?

Comment: You must assume something about the joint distribution of $X_n$ and $Y_n$, otherwise this result if false.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Sorry, I added the new condition that they are independent.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987810/joint-convergence-in-distribution